# DVD stuck in player, doesn't show in Finder or Desktop

Tags: mac

I've inserted a dvd into slot...doesn't show up in Finder,(DVD is checked in Finder Preferences), and won't eject! Tried to plastic card trick- no luck. Disk spinning in there but won't come out. I have tried holding the right click button upon restart, eject button and holding PC upside down. Disk still spinning but not ejecting!

Comment: Have you tried holding the space bar down on restart?

Answer (score 0):

Try in Terminal.app: `drutil tray eject`